# Superposition of Cubic Phase States, are they useful?

Tags: research, continuous-variable

Consider the context of continuous variable quantum information. Let $\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger$ be the creation and annihilation operators of a bosonic oscillator with the usual commutation relations $[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger]=\mathbb{I}$. Now, we usually define cubic phase states as $$|\gamma\rangle = e^{i \gamma \hat{q}^3 /3}|0\rangle$$ where $\hat{q}=(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$.

We know that cubic phase states are a useful resource to obtain universal quantum computing in bosonic systems [1]. There are protocols to approximately generate them starting from some other resource state such as a tri-squeezed state [2]. My question is: suppose I am able to generate a superposition of two opposite phase cubic phase states, i.e. the state $\propto |\gamma\rangle + |-\gamma\rangle$, is that useful for the same purposes a cubic phase state is useful? Are there any other potential use cases?

Thanks in advance!

1: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.062318
2: https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.010327#fulltext